# Why is the value of this variable changing to garbage once inside for-loop? C

Tags: c, for-loop, garbage

Why is the value of n changing to garbage inside the for-loop? (I'm new to C language, I come from a C++ background)

```
float n = 3.0;
printf ("%f\n", n);
for (; n <= 99.0; n += 2)
    printf ("%f\n", &n);
```

[image]

Comment: You are printing the address of an automatic variable. Remove the ampersand and you will print properly

Comment: Take away the & from your printf statement in the for loop.

Comment: @zz3599 Put as an answer and ye shall receive votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing the address of n (`&n`) inside the for-loop. Get rid of the `&`

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in how you're trying to print out `n`. You're passing the *address* of the `n` instead of the value.

You're gaining nothing by using floating point in this case. While it'll work, an `int` will work just as well:

```
int n = 3;
printf ("%d\n", n);
for (; n <= 99; n += 2)
    printf ("%d\n", n);
```

In C it's also more common to use `<` for your loop termination condition, so something like:

```
for ( ; n<100; n+=2)
```

...for the loop condition would *usually* be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

error in your for loop condition, you forgot to add suffix `f`:

do like:

```
for (; n <= 99.0f; n += 2)
                ^
```

remember: *unsuffixed* floating-point literals are doubles, which is a more commonly used floating point type than float.

second printf error: @adrianz answers

```
 printf ("%f\n", &n);
                 ^  remove it
```